# Difference between use and realize relationships uml interface

Tags: java, oop, interface, uml, relationships

what is the difference between use and realization interface relationships? How to implement them into code (e.g. java)? (Maybe better explanation of my question: I have one interface, say I and two classes, say A and B. Class A realizes I and class B uses I. What is difference between these relationships and how it should be implemented?) ... I have found many definitions but still I dont see difference.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

A the "realize" relationship is implemented in Java with:

```
class A implements I {
    ...
}
```

The "use" can be many things: it just says that class B uses interface I in one way or another. Examples:

```
class B {
   I aField;
   ...
   void doSomethingWith(I obj) { ... }
   I createAnI() { ... }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

As Maurice Perry said about Realize is correct.

To additional explain about Use Relationship in UML, it is a type of Dependency relationship. [see here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html)

A Use dependency relationship indicates that the consumer class does one of the following things:

- Temporarily uses a supplier class that has global scope,
- Temporarily uses a supplier class as a parameter for one of its operations,
- Temporarily uses a supplier class as a local variable for one of its operations,
  Sends a message to a supplier class.

[see IBM Documents here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_8.0.4/com.ibm.xtools.viz.cpp.doc/topics/cdependency.html)